# What is the word for 'haphazard' in the context of wardrobe?

Tags: word-request

Lets say I have a friend who always has his stuff scattered around the whole room or his wardrobe haphazardly, What word should I use to describe **the state of the room** or the wardrobe.

> He should do something about his room, It is so ..... that it is impossible for anyone to stand in there,

Comment: I think this is a bit too open-ended. The room might be *cluttered* (too many things in it), or it might be *messy/untidy/disorganised* (stuff badly situated so you can't get in or stand freely). Or other possible reasons, I don't know.

Comment: The room is so _twilight-zoneish_ that is imposible ...

Comment: Sometimes we use the term "fire-trap", though it doesn't fix in the example question. It means that if you were in the room you could not get out easily in case of a fire. Also all that clutter might start a fire.